# Clonezilla - dual boot - clone hdd to ssd

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clonezilla

I have a windows 10 + ubuntu 15.10 in a dual boot mode on my laptop.
My HDD is 1GB and my SSD is 250GB.
I managed to shrink my data in my HDD to be of size 226GB(all the other space is unallocated)
[image]
Now, I want to move the whole disk to the SSD.
When I tryed moving the disk using the disk-to-disk method, it told me that I have a bigger harddrive so it wasn't possible - this means that it doesn't look at how much space really is being used.

How can I solve this?
I don't want to reinstall the operating system..

Comment: You don't copy "disk to disk" if that doesn't work.  Look for an option to copy a partition.  You may need to do that multiple times.  After doing so, don't consider your job to be done until you verified that things boot okay.

Comment: You mean by using part-to-local-part?

Comment: I tried using part-to-local-part but when I need to select the destination partitions it doesn't show the ssd